# How to do the opposite of eager-loading in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I understand in Entity Framework you can specify relationships that need to be joined with **Include**:

```
Product firstProduct = 
       db.Product.Include("OrderDetail").Include("Supplier").First();
```

But we have the **opposite** issue that a simple LINQ statement is getting making **too *many* JOINs** on the SQL server.

So how do we do the opposite, i.e. tell Entity to **not** do any deep loading of joined tables when it gets all the orders, so that on the SQL Server it executes:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Entity Framework often goes ahead and loads basic relationship information too.

It does this so users can make updates easily, without violating the EF's unique concurrency policy for relationships.

You can turn this off however by doing a no tracking query.

See [Tip 11 - How to avoid relationship span for more information](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/04/07/tip-11-avoiding-relationship-span.aspx) for more information

Alex